# Mirroring sites

Tags: development-environment

what is the best way to mirror a site for development. My client has a fairly large site, half wordpress the other half custom php and I have to make fairly robust changes and would rather do it on development version.

Am I better of creating a sandbox on a separate server (?) what is the best way to do that if so?
Or just create a folder withing the same server?

Comment: Do you use version control?

Comment: I've never really used it. I use dropbox that has a similar function. My main worry is being able to make changes without it going live till the client has reviewed. And incase there are mistakes.

Comment: Version control is important for many things. In particular it helps keep track of different versions and branches in your development and synchronize deployments. Whether you work on the same server and guard development version with `.htaccess` or on a different server (preferably), `git` or `mercurial` would be helpfull.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Which one would be better, GIT? SO I could make changes and review them on server without it being on a live site?